# Changing the background colour in SharePoint 2010 Surveys

Tags: 2010, survey

Is it possible to change the font type and background color when I open a SharePoint 2010 survey? I have a basic understanding of HTML. The font I require is `Arial 8px` and the `background color #ff9900`. Any guidance provided will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using CSS:

Click on "respond to this survey" (hereby you access to the dispForm of the survey). Add there a Script Editor Web Part (or: Content Editor Web Part) and paste following code:

```
<style>
   .ms-gridT1{background-color: #ff9900; font-family: "Arial", Georgia, Serif; font-size: 8px; }
   .ms-gridCol {background-color: #ff9900; font-family: "Arial", Georgia, Serif; font-size: 8px;}
   .ms-formlabel {background-color: #ff9900; font-family: "Arial", Georgia, Serif; font-size: 8px;}
</style>
```

It works on SharePoint 2013. Please tell me if it works for SharePoint 2010 too.

If you want to color the complete background of the survey, use this code:

```
<style>
   .ms-webpart-zone{background-color: #ff9900; }
</style>
```

Comment: I think it will be "background-color: #ff9900;" not "color: #ff9900;" .. Questioner asking for bgcolor...

Comment: Hi SteffPoint - thanks for the code. Once clicking on the "Respond to this survey" button, the survey opens and I'm unable edit it let alone add a CEWP. Any thought as to how I can do so?

Comment: When u can add a CEWP, you can add my posted code into the CEWP -> Then it also works.

Comment: Or can't you generally edit the webpage? Do you have Site Owner rights?

Comment: Yep - I'm a site Admin. I can add a CEWP to a page as part of the edit / design process, but can't add one to a survey once the "Respond to survey" button has been clicked. I'll try adding your code to a page where I've linked to the survey and see what happens.

Comment: This won't work :) It has to be on the dispForm (displaying Page) of the survey

Comment: Click on "Respond to this survey" and change the URL in the top to this ending: /editForm.aspx?toolpaneview=2
Tell me if u know can add any Web Part

Comment: should look like: yourSite/THENAMEOFYOURSURVEY/editForm.aspx?toolpaneview=2

Comment: That was useful - I'm able to add a web part (CEWP for example) but unable to add the code in the HTML editor as the ribbon isn't available to select that option. Thoughts..?

Comment: Is it possible that you can add a Script Editor Web Part?
You will find it, like the Content Editor Web Part, in the media and content section of the Web Parts

Comment: Within a Script Editor you can simply add this Code and then it's done.

Comment: Within Content Editor Web Part: There is also an option in the ribbon  to "Embed Code" (under "Insert"), try if this is selectable for you and add there the Code

Comment: I can't find the Script editor web part - think it may be something unique to SP2013..? I'm unable to access the ribbon on my page in order to place code in the HTML editor. Could this be down to the type of page I'm developing?

Comment: Could you please give me a quick summary of your rights and on which page this survey app (In the Site Contents) is placed. U need to have at least editing rights for the Site Collection Page where this app is hosted. Otherwise u have to ask the Site Owner of this Site to do this little job for you (embeding the Code on this Site).

Comment: I'm a site owner, so have full control - this has been confirmed by my collection administrator.

Comment: So there is one way left you can try by linking your CSS file in the Content Editor Web Part you added on the Survey dispForm (form after "Respond to this survey"): http://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2014/10/10/adding-a-code-snippet-to-page-content-on-sharepoint-2013/

Please see here the last option 4: save as a text file, call via CEWP
As preparation for this step you should open a new textdocument on your computer, post my code from top into it, save it with the ending ".css" and upload it to any library on your Site.

Comment: Then take the link of your uploaded CSS file and link it how it is described in the Tutorial. Good luck trying this :) Hope it works